# What is a proxy?

Tags: proxy

I've scoured the Internet, but I always see the word "proxy" attached to another word, like a proxy server or something. Someone else told me that proxies in relation to Hibernate has something to do with the ID of a table's element. But what does proxy in itself mean??

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proxy: ... Noun: ... (software) An interface for a service, especially for one that is remote, resource-intensive, or otherwise difficult to use directly.

Answer (score 2):

The word `proxy` refers to one entity acting in the place of another.  In context,

- proxy server: a server that acts as an intermediary between two machines.
- Hibernate proxy: instead of returning data, Hibernate generally return proxies that need to be called in order to get the data.

In both cases, the proxy provides certain benefits (caching results, delaying execution until necessary)